# packaging public data with R

Tags: r, nlp, packaging

I'm a college student who is interested in participating a hackathon for packaging public data with R.

This is my first time with R, packaging and public data. So I have few concerns that I'd like to be advised.
In order for me to participate the activity, I have to prepare a packaging idea with a simple business logic referring to how the package can do good to other businesses. My friend and I are currently working on developing a plan for a package that organizes csv files concerning bicycle roads and relevant gadget stations the government is providing access to individuals.

1. How many functions should we devise for the plan? As I am new to packaging, other than few (about 4) simple functions like returning the number and the location of outdated gadgets if received the name of the region, I can't really imagine what to do with it.
2. Has anybody made a package for natural language processing with R using public data? I would like if this hackathon experience relate to my study of nlp but considering the nature of the language R, I'm thinking maybe this isn't the right project to plan for this time.

Thank you in advance for your comment :)

Comment: Hi, I've made a few R packages (unfortunately not NLP ones though), here are a few resources I found useful: [Hadley Wickham's R package book](https://r-pkgs.org/), [Hillary Parker's highly cited blog](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) and I wrote a [quick post](https://josephcrispell.github.io/2018/09/11/creating-R-package.html) about it to. In Hadley's book, there is a good section on including data [here](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html). Good luck!

Comment: @JosephCrispell Wow! thank you, I'll check it out :DD